# How to move FullCalendar plugin to the center?

Tags: html, css, fullcalendar

The fullcalendar jquery plugin I'm using is stuck to the left side of the browser how do I center it?

```
<div id="calender"style="width: 80%; display: inline-block; "></div>
```

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/114549/6383857) might be useful

Comment: `margin:0 auto;` should do... But with `display:block`.

Comment: most of the tags you used have nothing to do with the question. I added some more relevant ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your div with `<center> </center>` tags

```
<center> <div id="calender"style="width: 80%; display: inline-block; "></div> </center>
```

or

> You can apply this CSS to the :
>
> `#inner {   width: 50%;   margin: 0 auto; }`